# All data in my Database are update. How to update 1 row only?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConstring))                                  
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn)                    
{                        
    conn.Open();                    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?compname", Tb_AddWsComp.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?alloc", Tb_AddWsAlloc.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?department", Cb_AddWsDepart.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?facility", Cb_AddWsFacility.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?ipadd", Tb_AddWsIpAd.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?emailadd", Tb_AddWsEmail.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?os", Cb_AddWsOs.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?processor", Tb_AddWsProcess.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?memory", Tb_AddWsMemory.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?pkey", Cb_AddWsPkey.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?mskey", Tb_AddWsOfficeKey.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?sophos", Cb_AddWsSophos.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("belarcdate", belarcDate);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?remarks", Tb_AddWsRemarks.Text);                        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?sysadmin", Tb_AddWsSysAd.Text);

    MessageBox.Show("Updated");                        
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
    conn.Close();
}

string query = "UPDATE addwsinventory SET compname =?compname,alloc=? alloc,department=?department,facility=?fac‌​ility,  
ipadd=?ipadd,e‌​mailadd= emailadd,os‌​=?os,processor=?proc‌​essor,memory=?memory‌​,pkey=?pkey,mskey=?m‌​ skey,sophos=?sophos,‌​  
belarcdate=?belarcda‌​te,remarks=?remarks,‌​sysadmin=sysadmin ";
```

The above code was working but all data in my Database has been modified, how do I fix this?

Comment: string query = "UPDATE addwsinventory SET compname =?compname,alloc=?alloc,department=?department,facility=?facility,ipadd=?ipadd,emailadd=?emailadd,os=?os,processor=?processor,memory=?memory,pkey=?pkey,mskey=?mskey,sophos=?sophos,belarcdate=?belarcdate,remarks=?remarks,sysadmin=?sysadmin ";

Comment: Add a where clause to your update statement.

Answer (score 0):

[Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) will change the existing data, you need to specify which data to change using [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql).

```
UPDATE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name   
SET { column_name = { expression | NULL } } [ ,...n ]  
[ FROM from_clause ]  
[ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
[ OPTION ( LABEL = label_name ) ]  
[;]
```

So if would be:

```
string query = "UPDATE addwsinventory SET compname .../... WHERE <your condition> ";
```

Use [Insert](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx) to insert into the database, if you just want to add a new value.

```
INSERT [INTO] table_or_view [(column_list)] data_values
```